# SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: php, sql-server, forms

I have a table in MS SQL Server database. The datatypes for the fields are `INT`, `NUMERIC`, and `NVARCHAR`. I have **EDIT** option at the back of each row in the table. When the **EDIT**
 option is clicked, it brings to a form where we can enter the values to be updated. The issue I am having is: When I leave the form's field empty for the datatype `NUMERIC`, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Also, in the edit.php some inputs have dropdowns. I want to assign different background colors for different options. The code snippet for edit.php is:

```
<?php
require_once('include/database.php');

if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
if (isset($_POST['txt_id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['txt_id'];
} else {
    $id = '';
}


 if (isset($_POST['txt_arc_capacity'])) {    //Its datatype is NUMERIC(25).  
    $arc = $_POST['txt_arc_capacity'];
} else {
    $arc = 0;
}

if (isset($_POST['txt_qrating'])) {        //It has dropdowns, namely Q1, Q2,Q3,Q4. I want to assign when the value is Q1(background color: green) 
    $qrating = $_POST['txt_qrating'];
} else {
    $qrating = '';
}

 try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE MATRIX SET  ARC_Capacity=:arc,
                                               Q_Rating=:qrating
                                               WHERE OBJECTID =:id");


 $stmt->execute(array(':arc' => $arc, ':qrating'=>$qrating, ':id' => $id));

 if ($stmt) {


        header('Location:index.php');
        exit();

    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}

$object_id='';
$arc = '';
$qrating = '';

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MATRIX WHERE OBJECTID=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $object_id = $row['OBJECTID'];
        $arc = $row['ARC_Capacity'];
        $qrating = $row['Q_Rating'];
 }
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit the Data</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Edit the records</h2>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <table border="3px" cellpadding="5px"> 

    <tr>
                <td>ARC Capacity (estimate PN)</td>
                <td><label>
                    <input type="text" name="txt_arc_capacity" value=
                    "<?=$arc; ?>"></label></td>
            </tr>


     <tr>
                <td>Q Rating</td>
                <td><label>
                        <select name="txt_qrating" class="textfields" id="design">
                            <option id="0">Select One</option>
                            <?php
                            require_once('include/database.php');
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MATRIX_DROPDOWNS");
                            $stmt ->execute();
                            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
                            foreach($result as $row){
                                ?>

                                <option id="<?=$row['OBJECTID'];?>"><?=$row['Q_Rating']?></option>

                            <?php } ?>



                        </select>


                    </label>
                </td>

            <tr>

     <tr>
                <td><label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="txt_id" value="<?= $object_id; ?>">
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td><label><input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit">
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is `Q_Rating` possibly an int column? Also, I don't see where `$id` is being set

Comment: Q_Rating is NVARCHAR type. I just added the $id. Sorry about that. Thanks